# How can I initialize a class function with another function?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, code-generation, generator

I'm trying to initialize an array of Fibonacci numbers so I can later use them in a tableview. Right now, this is how I'm trying to do it but getting an issue: "Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type of '(Int?)'" at fibonacciNumbers.append( )

```
class FibonacciNumbers {

 class func getTheFibonacciNumbers(allResults: NSArray) -> [FibonacciNumbers] {

    // Create an empty array of Fibonacci Numbers to append to from this list
    var fibonacciNumbers = [FibonacciNumbers]()
    var number = generate()

    // Store the results in our table data array
    if allResults.count>0 {

        for result in allResults {

            fibonacciNumbers.append(number.next()) //Getting issue here
        }
    }

     return fibonacciNumbers
  }

}

func generate() -> GeneratorOf<Int> {
 var current = 0, next = 1
 return GeneratorOf<Int> {
     var ret = current
     current = next
     next = next + ret
     return ret
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For generators, `next()` returns an optional value. However, since your generator is designed to never stop producing numbers, you can safely use `next()!`.

The other problem is that your `generate()` function produces a generator of Ints, which means that `numbers.next()!` will be an Int. So your `fibonacciNumbers` array needs to be `[Int]`.

<sup>Shameless plug for [my own post about Fibonacci Numbers](http://bandes-stor.ch/blog/2015/08/05/the-fibonacci-sequencetype/) :)</sup>

Comment: That won't work - he still tries to put an Int in an array of `FibonacciNumbers`

Comment: Cool thanks! I didn't see your site before, but I'm checking it out now. Your solution provided here however did not fix the issue.

Comment: I'm still a little confused because if I change the fibonacciNumbers array to [Int] that gives an error because the return type of the class is FibonacciNumbers. If I change both the return types to [int] there is no compile issue but I am getting an empty array when I am calling it.

Comment: If you're getting an empty array, then perhaps `allResults.count` is zero. The number of fibonacci numbers that you're including is tied to that. What is the purpose of `allResults`?

Comment: You're right. allResults does not need to be there. I need to rewrite this. Thanks for all your help though